# A div with CSS width:100% gets shorter by increasing the IE zoom level

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zooming

I have a div with the following CSS

```
        div.bottom {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
          height: 13px; width: 100%;
          background-image:  url("../../image/icon/login_bottom.gif");
          background-repeat: repeat-x;
        }
```

this div is covering the whole width of the IE window when the zoom level of IE is 100%, but when I increase the zoom level this div is getting shorter.

I want to have the width of 100% in all zoom levels to cover the whole window's width.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It gets shorter because you tell the div to be 100% if you zoom on 150% it will stay on the 100% width of IE so the more you zoom the smaller it seems to be. Not sure but it's what i think.

I dont know what your purposes are but it's possible to work with css scale

```css
#div { zoom: 3; -moz-transform: scale(3); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0 }
```

Comment: When I have maximize IE window, my div is covering the whole with of the window till zoom level 195%. After zoom level 195% it is getting shorter.

Comment: when I have not maximize windows , the problem start in zoom level 125%

Comment: I can't help you much further then this, I don't have IE installed on my Macbook I just explained how I would fix it if I was.

Comment: zoom: 3 helps, but it zooms in three times even in normal(100%) IE zoom level.

Comment: Last thing you can try is change the height in % aswell, else i can't help you, goodluck :)